# Is it possible to extract specific sentences with same certain format and save them to a text file in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, extract

For example, when examining a document that is a novel or fiction, I wonder if I can get all the dialogues?
Because they have the same format, like "What a nice day!" and "Hello!" that are confined to two quotation marks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I wonder if I can get all the dialogues"?

Comment: Like extracting them to a text file.

Comment: Edit your question and add that you want them extracted/saved to a text file. You did not mention it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you use unique styles to format your text, this would be a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBA to automate the process.

1. Open the document.
2. Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA Editor.
3. Copy and paste the code below.
4. With your cursor inside the code, press F5 to run it. A new window will be opened with the extracted dialogues.

```vba
Sub GetDialogues()

    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim regEx As RegExp
    Dim allMatches As MatchCollection
    
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    
    With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True    'Look for all matches
        .Pattern = """.+?"""    'Pattern to look for
    End With
 
    Set allMatches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
 
    For Each Item In allMatches
        coll.Add Item   'Add found items to the collection
    Next Item

    Dim newdoc As Document
    Set newdoc = Documents.Add  'Add a new Word document
    newdoc.Activate             'Activate the document

    For Each Item In coll
        newdoc.Content.Text = newdoc.Content.Text + Item   'Add each item (quote) to the document
    Next Item

    newdoc.SaveAs FileName:="test.txt", Fileformat:=wdFormatPlainText   'Save the document as plain text

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it kinda works for me.

Comment: You should mark the question as solved if it has been answered successfully. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)